# Why am I getting a segmentation fault? C, basic code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, c-strings, string-literals, function-definition

Why I am getting a segmentation fault? Unlike other similar questions posted here, it doesn't seem to me that I'm trying to access an array index that is out of memory.

What I want the `squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])` function to do, is to delete every char that occurs in `s2` from `s1` and print the result.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[]);

int main()
{
    squeeze("test string", "ts");
    
    return 0;
}

void squeeze(char s1[], char s2[])
{
    int i, j, k;

    for (k = 0; s2[k] != '\0'; k++) {
        for (i=j=0; s1[i] != '\0'; i++)
            if (s1[i] != s2[k]) {
                s1[j] = s1[i];
                ++j;
            }
        s1[j] = '\0';
    }
    printf("%s", s1);
}
```

Error occurs on the line `s1[j] = s1[i];`, when I tried to separate it into two lines and use another char as a placeholder, the segfault was on line with `s1[j]`.

I also tried to use gdb, and I could read both `s1[j]` and `s1[i]`.

Here is the segfault message from gdb:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
squeeze (s1=0x555555556007 "test string", s2=0x555555556004 "ts") at main.c:18
18                  s1[j] = s1[i];
```

I've recently started learning C, and I have no idea what is the problem.

Comment: Because `"test string"` is a *string literal* which is read-only. But `s1[j] = s1[i];` is attempting to write to it, as reported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C standard does not define the behavior of attempting to write into the array of a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). `"test string"` is a string literal.

Instead of passing it directly to `squeeze`, define an array of `char`, initialize that array with the string literal, and pass that array to `squeeze`:

```
char buffer[] = "test string";
squeeze(buffer, "ts");
```

Answer (score 1):

In this call

```
squeeze("test string", "ts");
```

you are trying to change a string literal. Though in C opposite to C++ string literals have non-constant character array types nevertheless any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior.

You should declare a character array and initialize it with the string literal as for example

```
char s1[] = "test string";
squeeze( s1, "ts");
```

Also the function should be declared like

```
char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] );
```

And the used approach is inefficient.

The function can be defined the following way as shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * squeeze( char s1[], const char s2[] )
{
    if ( *s2 )
    {
        char *p = s1, *q = s1;

        do
        {
            if ( *p == '\0' || strchr( s2, *p ) == NULL )
            {
                if ( p != q ) *q = *p;
                ++q; 
            }
        } while ( *p++ );
    }

    return s1;
}

int main( void )
{
    char s1[] = "test string";

    puts( squeeze( s1, "ts" ) );
}
```

The program output is

```
e ring
```